# In microsoft word I want to show more information in the citation

Tags: citations, microsoft-word

I have a citation in a word doc and want to show more information in the reference text on the page.

So we have
[image]

I want to change (Heymann,2020) to "Heymann, D. (2020, May 4). Malaria"

I have looked in the References tab and can't find any way to change this in the options for style or insert a footnote, bibliography etc
[image]